# Meaning of "a distribution does not live on any proper subinterval of $(-\infty,\infty)$".

Tags: measure-theory

While I am reading a probability note related to Radon-Nikodym derivative, I found the sentence I could not understand easily:

"Assume that the distribution $\mu$ does not live on any proper subinterval of $(-\infty,\infty)$."

It would be very helpful if someone could give me a view on this comment.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It means that no proper subinterval of $(-\infty,\infty)$ is s support for the distribution.If you do not know the concept of support of a measure see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(measure_theory))

Comment: Does this then mean the measure should take the entire real line as its support?

Comment: yeah! it is so!

Comment: Not quite. Consider $\mu=\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}, k \neq 0} 1_k / 2^{|k|+1}$, where $1_k$ is 1 if $k$ is in the set and zero otherwise. This measure does not live on any subinterval, and it's support is not the real line.